# How do I count rows in a table according to ID column (prepared statements)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an array populated with records from one table and want to count corresponding records from another table and insert that into the array.

When I try this code I keep getting this error

> Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: All data must be fetched before a new statement prepare takes place

```
foreach ($persons as $i=>$person)
{ 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order WHERE personId = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $person['personId']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($totalOrders);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close;       
    $persons[$i]['totalOrders'] = $totalOrders;
}
```

It's as though the `$stmt->close;` is being ignored.

Comment: "I have an array populated with records from one table and want to count corresponding records from another table and insert that into the array." - Why not use a JOIN with a GROUP BY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parentheses to call the close method:

```
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Doh! Been calling it like that before and it wasn't complaining so I figured it was right. But I was fetching all data before. I realise this is the wrong way to go about things anyway, I should be using joins and subqueries but it baby steps for me and mysql at this stage.